# How to resolve error in Holtwinters forecast model with R?

Tags: r, forecast, holtwinters

I have simple monthly dataset and simply trying this code:

```
`df2.holtwinters <- subset(df, account_id==loopitem) 
  x.holtwinters <- ts(df2.holtwinters$amount_usd, start = c(2015,1), end = c(2019,5), frequency = 12)
  arima1.holtwinters <- HoltWinters(x.holtwinters)
  forecast1.holtwinters <- predict(arima1.holtwinters, n.ahead=1*1)
```

The dataset look like this:

```
`      id     <date>         <dbl>
1     123  2015-01-01       -390
2     123  2015-02-01        944
3     999  2015-01-01        672
```

It is giving following erros:

```
`In HoltWinters(x.holtwinters) :
  optimization difficulties: ERROR: ABNORMAL_TERMINATION_IN_LNSRCH
```

Comment: Can you post your dataset?

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot see which data you are using, it is not easy to say what went wrong, but here is an example code which might be helpful.
Let's get retail data from Rob Hyndman's website

```
library(forecast)

retail <- read.csv("https://robjhyndman.com/data/ausretail.csv",header=FALSE)
```

remove date column and create a mts classed data

```
retail <- stats::ts(retail[,-1], start = c(1982,4), frequency = 12)
```

plot the first time series (first column)

```
plot(retail[,1])
```

fit Holt Winters to first time series in the data

```
fit <- HoltWinters(retail[,1])
```

use predict function to get forecast as you did

```
fc <- predict(fit, n.ahead = 12)

plot(fc)
```

Or you can use forecast function to get a forecast output which is nice.

```
fc <- forecast(fit, n.ahead = 12)

plot(fc)
```

using AirPassengers data if for some reasons you could not get retail data

```
fit <- HoltWinters(AirPassengers)

fc <- predict(fit, n.ahead = 12)

plot(fc)
```

or you can use forecast function to get a forecast output

```
fc <- forecast(fit, n.ahead = 12)

plot(fc)
```

forecasting loop for many time series

```
nts <- ncol(retail) # number of time series

h = 12 # forecast horizon

fc <- matrix(nrow = h, ncol = nts)

for (i in 1:nts) {

  fc[,i] <- forecast(HoltWinters(retail[,i]), h = h)$mean # it will return point forecast
  
}

colnames(fc) <- colnames(retail)

fc
```

I would recommend to take look into `fable` package.